# SQLite Sorting TEXT field

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following table:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST_TABLE ( testID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, testName TEXT);`

Some of the test data

1. Test
2. Hello
3. aa
4. World

My Query

`SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE ORDER BY testName`

Response:

1. Hello
2. Test
3. World
4. aa

Expected:

1. aa
2. Hello
3. Test
4. World

Can someone explain why this is the response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE ORDER BY testName COLLATE NOCASE;
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because ORDER BY is case sensitive and a 'a' is greater than a 'Z'. There is a solution to be case insensitive : `[Your request] ORDER BY testName COLLATE NOCASE`

Hope this could explain your problem.

Edit : dom explain it before :-)